# Is this true formula :$\lim_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)=\exp(-\infty)=0$ for student in high school level?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, education

Inspectors of mathematics recomonded teachers  that this formula $\exp(-\infty)$  as a second step for computation of $\lim_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)$ as $x \to -\infty$ is not true in mathematics and it is a scientific error . In my Humbel opinion as a teacher in high school that the titled formula is true and there is no problem to consider it in any mathematical contexts , Now my question here is :

Is really this formula includes scientific error  in mathematics 
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)=\exp(-\infty)=0$$

?

Comment: Perhaps they are objecting to the expression $\exp(-\infty)$...unless you just define that to be the limit in question, it has no obvious meaning.

Comment: I meant  the substitution when student want to compute that limit

Comment: What substitution?  $-\infty$ isn't a value that you can plug in.  Like I say, it makes some sense to $\mathit {define}$ $\exp(-\infty)$ via this limit but you then can't use it while attempting to compute the limit.

Answer (score 2):

$\exp(-\infty)$ has no sense, because $\exp$ is a function that takes as an argument a number, and $-\infty$ is not a number.

Answer (score -1):

Formally $-\infty$ is not a real number, so $\exp(-\infty)$ does not make sense. However you may add the symbol $-\infty$ to the reals and define $\exp(-\infty)$ to be $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \exp x$.

Comment: If you do use that definition then $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)=\exp(-\infty)=0$ becomes a little circular

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The original question is essentially "what is $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)$ ?" and the original suggestion is that using  $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)=\exp(-\infty)$ will help.  You then suggest using the definition that $\exp(-\infty)= \lim\limits_{x\to -\infty } \exp (x)$, which seems to go back to the start

Comment: I am not suggesting anything. I am just saying that one can make sense of the expression $\exp(-\infty)$ defining it as the limit in question. This does not affect the result, it is just a way of formalising the expression $\exp(-\infty)$.

Comment: For example Wolfram alpha define it to be 0 then you can define it

Comment: Wolfram alpha has nothing to do with this. I am just making sense of the expression $\exp (-\infty)$.

Comment: Then it is not error scientifics when  when student attempt to compute the titled limit

Comment: It does not make sense as long as you work on $\mathbb{R}$, which I guess is what happens at high school. You can make sense of the expression $\exp(-\infty)$ working on an extension of $\mathbb{R}$.